# nginx location deny by file extension syntax

Tags: linux, security, nginx

I wrote two different settings, one for denying access to dotfiles, and the other for denying access to a list of file extensions.

But, is there any syntax that could deny dotfiles in the list of other file extensions?

```
location ~* \.(7z|bak|bash|bz2|config|dist|engine|fla|git|gz|inc|inc|info|ini|install|iso|log|make|module|profile|psd|py|rar|rb|sh|sql|swp|tar|zip)$ {
deny all;
}

location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the "dotfiles"

Comment: Dotfiles as in any file beginning with a dot, any configuration or rc file typically found on Unix based systems, such as .htaccess, .bashrc, .zshrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) server [uses](http://ngx.su/src/core/ngx_regex.c) straight [pcre](http://ports.su/devel/pcre) as the library for regular expressions; whatever pcre accepts, so should nginx.

Some testing on OpenBSD with [`egrep(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/grep.1) reveals:

`$ printf '/t.bak\n/t.bakk\n/t.zipp\n/a.zip\n/.ht\n/t.ht\n' |grep -E '\.(bak|zip)$|/\.'
/t.bak
/a.zip
/.ht
$`

But [OpenBSD's `egrep`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.bin/grep/grep.c#Eflag) doesn't actually use pcre, but [`regcomp(3)`](http://mdoc.su/o/regcomp.3) instead!  However, pcre does come with `pcregrep`, which does produce identical results:

`$ printf '/t.bak\n/t.bakk\n/t.zipp\n/a.zip\n/.ht\n/t.ht\n' |pcregrep '\.(bak|zip)$|/\.'
/t.bak
/a.zip
/.ht
$`

You could also try `pcretest` for testing the regular expressions (apparently, you must quote them with something like `#` there):

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.30 2012-02-04

  re> #\.(bak|zip)$|/\.#
data> /t.bak
 0: .bak
 1: bak
data> /t.baki
No match
data> /.h
 0: /.
data> ^D
$
```

I.e., to summarise: **just concatenating the two expressions with `|` should work**.

```
location ~* \.(bak|zip)$|/\. {
    deny all;
}
```

However, for the sake of maintenance (and since you've had to ask this question in the first place), you might as well want to keep these expressions apart for a clearer overview of what the config is all about.  (The two expressions apart might even be more efficient due to some kind of end-of-line optimisation than when merged together, but that's just a wild guess on my part.)